# What are the comparison operators in case statement formula?

Tags: crystal-reports, comparison-operators

Working with Crystal Reports 2016.  My select case statement has 3 possible values, 0 through 2. I want to assign text labels for them in a chart. Crystal Reports says I can't use `=` as a comparison operator, which is weird because [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664201(v=vs.71).aspx) says it is a comparison operator (as opposed to an assignment operator). What operator should I use?

This code check out according to the formula Workshop:

```
select ({CRV_AttributeLog.AnalogValue})
  case is < 1: "Offline"
  case is <= 1: "Partially Online"
  case is > 1: "Online"
  default: "Unknown";
```

This is what i want to do:

```
select ({CRV_AttributeLog.AnalogValue})
  case is = 0: "Offline"
  case is = 1: "Partially Online"
  case is = 2: "Online"
  default: "Unknown";
```

`==` also does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the 'is =' portion in the select statement .. see below

```
select ({CRV_AttributeLog.AnalogValue})
  case 0: "Offline"
  case 1: "Partially Online"
  case 2: "Online"
  default: "Unknown";
```